# Rails bootstrap Datepicker not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to implement datepicker to a rails app , so i have been able to run it in reference with these two links :

http://jakoblaegdsmand.com/blog/2012/05/rails-datetime-picker/
https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

For some reason it runs just fine when i run it with a scaffold but when i try to run it by building a rails application from scratch by building a model,controller,view respectively its not running,basically nothing happens when i click on the date text field.

This is the following code that i have written.

In the Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

IN the appplication.css

```
*= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

In the application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

In the _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :Name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %><br/>
<%= f.label :Description %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :description %><br/>
<%= f.label :EmailID %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :emailid %><br/>
<%= f.label :Date %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :cdate, :class => 'datepicker', 'placeholder'=> "dd-mm-yyyy" %><br/>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
  </script>
<% end %>
```

In Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150312163128) do
```

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "emailid"
    t.text     "description"
    t.date     "cdate"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end

So kindly tell what i am doing wrong , have been stuck at this since 3 days.

Comment: Is there anything in chrome's developer tools which indicates errors with JS?

Comment: ya it says "uncaught reference error :jquery is not defined"  and an   "Uncaught TypeError : undefined is not a function"  for this line "$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});" , i have uploaded the code to git u can find it here :  https://github.com/nickkevin/testdate

Comment: I tried this and its working fine for me. As specified error by you is clearly says that jquery is not defined. It means jquery is not loading properly or its getting load after datepicker. Please check sequence of JavaScript you included.

Comment: Anuja's 100% on the money with that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your [gihub link](http://github.com/nickkevin/testdate). And your sequence is wrong. Jquery and jquery-ui should always be first in sequence.

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Try updating this as follows:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: yup works , as you said got the sequence wrong in calling the files. thanks. i have tried to implement a start date and end date to it dynamically by writing the following code :-

Comment: What exactly you trying to do it that method?

Comment: well i am trying to set a start and end date dynamically ,so as the day goes by ,it takes current date value and so by it all previous dates are disabled and i am setting a counter of 30 so any date under these 30 days is available, so is this the best way to write it ,or can i make the code much more efficient.